# SwiftMailer not sending to other domain

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I've been trying to use the the SwiftMailer library for PHP for sending emails. It works fine during the development. However, when in actual use, it appears to be sending only to a particular domain only. For example, if I have users for `domain.com` and `another_domain.com` and use the SMTP server `server.domain.com`, emails are only received by users at `domain.com`.

There are no errors, however. Below is the log:

```
<< server.domain.com Hello [10.xx.xx.xx], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP

++ Swift_SmtpTransport started
>> MAIL FROM: <server.test@domain.com>

<< 250 2.1.0 <server.test@domain.com>... Sender ok

>> RCPT TO: <user@domain.com>

<< 250 2.1.5 <user@domain.com>... Recipient ok

>> DATA

<< 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself

>> 
.

<< 250 2.0.0 sxxxxxxxxxxxxx Message accepted for delivery

>> MAIL FROM: <server.test@domain.com>

<< 250 2.1.0 <server.test@domain.com>... Sender ok

!! Connection to server.domain.com:25 Timed Out
>> RSET

<< 250 2.1.5 <another_user@another_domain.com>... Recipient ok
```

Below is the code that I used.

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject($subject)
  ->setFrom(array($from))
  ->setTo($to)
  ->setBody($message, 'text/html');
if (isset($file)) $message = $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file));
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($smtp_server, $smtp_port);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
return $mailer->send($message);
```

Do I have to make some corrections to the code or is this an external issue?

Comment: I confirmed it to the users and they said, the client do not have a spam a folder, so I guess no.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the email takes a longer time sending to external addresses than when sending to internal addresses. I can't seem to find a timeout option for SwiftMailer so I instead switched to the PHPMailer library since it provides the Timeout option. Setting the SMTP server timeout to a higher values fixes the problem.